# Is it possible to display the table records with dynamic columns using mvc3

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, dynamic-programming, data-access-layer

I'm working with asp. Net mvc3 and i'm using sql server 2008 as backend.I have to display a table in front end that will have a dynamic columns is it possible in c# for example 1st time when I execute stored procedure it'll return 4 columns with values and next time  it'll return 5 columns with values I shouldnot make any code changes when one more column added to the table in backend is it possible in asp .net mvc3? Is anyone of u faced such a scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I think it might be easier if you would use an ORM like Entity Framework, instead of ADO.NET.

For the frontend I would recommend Grid.MVC. Here's an simple example to get you started
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/597253/Using-the-Grid-MVC-in-ASP-NET-MVC

For the frontend you could use an if in the cshtml file such as:

```
@{
    if(Model.Property != null) //Receives 4 columns, 1 Property is initialized with NULL
    {
         //Render grid with 4 columns
    }
    else  // Receives 5 columns, all properties !=null
    {
         //Render grid with 5 columns
    }
}
```

If you feel more comfortable with javascript, you can use jqgrid.

Comment: if i'm adding new column in backend table is it possible to add in frontend without adding its properties?i.e.if the column added after the code is deployed is it possible to add the same column in front end without doing any code change?

Comment: If the model doesn't have the column mapped, it will not be shown in the frontend. On the other hand if you want to show it, EF can execute quite easily SQL queries.

Comment: Also, you can return the grid's html as ContentResult from an action and generate the html in the backend.